# Execute shell command as the part of pom.xml

Tags: java, rspec, jruby

I am a ROR web app developer. I wrote rspec test cases for a "java application rest api". I execute rspec from the dir test_api(where all test1.rb test2.rb test3.rb..files resides). Ex as below

```
base_dir/specs >> jruby -S rspec --color test_api/
```

Now i want to execute it as the part of mvn(may be pom.xml). My test cases need server to be up for running.

I dont know how to do this. Please suggest how to do this.

Should i execute these test cases as shell command Or i should use some mvn plugin. And how?

Comment: Haven't used it myself, but maybe you can use the [rspec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rspec-maven-plugin/)?

Comment: If i use rspec-maven-plugin, do i need to add other gems which i m using for executing specs as dependency or rspec-maven-plugin will take care of it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a really bad idea to have external dependencies that your unit tests need in order to run, however if you really need to do this, then look at the [Maven Exec Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html).

You should configure Maven to skip the `test` [phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) and run the `integration-test` [phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) attaching the [Maven Exec Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html) twice, once to `pre-integration-test` to start the server and again to `post-integration-test` to stop the server.

**Update:**

Again, I would necessarily advise this and would look at the RSpec plugin that @NilsH refers to in his comment on the question.